# How to wait for chain of subscriptions finishes?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I 'm still struggling with the Observables, cause I'm coding a complex REST API query function with complex logic and multiple requests and response.

I already wrote lots of functions with subscription like these,

```
function1(){
   thisReturnsAnObservable()
    .subscribe();
}

function2(){
   thisReturnsAnObservable()
    .subscribe();
}

function3(){
   thisReturnsAnObservable()
    .subscribe();
}
```

And in the function with multiple queries, I code it like this

```
complexFunction(){
  function1();
  function2();
  function3();
  if (aVariableChangedBy123 == true){
    doSomething();
  }
}
```

I think I'm confused, the experiment proves me wrong, because, the variable aVariableChangedBy123 is always get evaluated before function1,2,3 finishes, so what I want is since the aVariableChangedBy123 only will be certain after function1,2,3 finished one by one sequentially, how should I code a function to chain these function with subscribes, to make them run sequentially?

I knew there can be ways like rewriting all the function1,2,3 but is there a way no need to write those functions, because I can reuse them in other situations?

I've tried to use the `flatMap()` function that I knew can chain them like `then()`, but the code always give error on runtime, like `Cannot read property 'flatMap' of undefined`, since all the funtion1,2,3 are void functions.

I got a way, but I don't know if it is right.

like

```
Observable.forkJoin(Observable.of(function1),Observable.of(function2)).subscribe() ;
```

Is this viable? Never thought I can use it statically...

Comment: Check for `flatMap`(now `mergeMap` with rxjs5) and `forkJoin`

Comment: they seem not working for me, sometimes they just give me void[] is not assignable to parameter of type SubscribableOrPromise<any> error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `map` or `switchMap` operators and each function should return a subscription so it can go to next function. In this way you will subscribe only in your last method and your function will run in a sequence.

Comment: is there a way that I dont need to change those void functions.